# Content not displaying when window resizes?

Tags: html, css

When I resize this page, my image div displays, but the form div in the page does not. Why is this? Also how do I have the image div show on top and the form div (which is not displaying) show below the image div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

}
```

How do I have the image div show on top and the form div (which is not displaying) show below the image div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed both of the issues you were having. Here are the things I have changed:

1. Removing the `float` from the `.image` class (It wasn't necessary as it was in a flex container)

2. From the media query, I removed the `flex-direction` so that the image div shows on top on smaller screens
3. I also had to properly place the `</form>` closing tag

```css
:root {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

html {
    overflow: scroll;

}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(234, 232, 232, 0.857);
    display: grid;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
}

.image{
    /* float:left; */
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 55vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1000/1000") no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
    /* background-size: 55vw 100vh; */
} 

.header {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.6;

}
h1{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; 
}

.form {
    /* display: flex; */
    display: block;
    /* justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 0%;
}

.b-container{
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.body1{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-left: 1.1rem;
}

.subheading {
    margin-top: 10px;
}



.center {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 0.6rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 0.6rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.right{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 0.6rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.form-label {
    font-weight: 900;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.form-input {
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
}

.m-container{
    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

}

.middle {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 1rem;

} 
.inputs{
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 40px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 120%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.123);
}

.container2{  
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.btn{
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer; 
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 4px 15px 4px 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(201, 212, 254);;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: rgb(201, 212, 254);;
    white-space: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 130px;
    margin-left: 1.1rem;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1.2rem; 
    margin-left: 1.1rem;
}

.errorMessage{
    margin-left: 1.1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.1rem;
}

.imageDiv{
    display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container{
        /* display: flex; */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        /* flex-direction: column-reverse; */
    }

    .image{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 50vh;

        background-size: cover;
    }

    .form {

        width: 100%;

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class= "container">
        <div class="image">
            <div class="header">
                
                <h1>SIGN-UP FORM</h1> 
            
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="form">
            
                <div class="b-container">
                    <div class="body1">
                        <b>THIS IS A DEMO SIGN-UP PAGE. SIGN UP NOW TO GET STARTED.</b>
                        
                        <div class="subheading"><b>LETS DO THIS!</b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
                
                    
                <form action="">
                        <div class="middle">
                            <div class="inputs">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <div class="first-name">
                                        <label class="form-left" style="font-size: 1.2rem;">First Name: </label>
                                        <input required type="text" class="form-input" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name">  
                                    </div>
                    
                                    <div class="email">
                                        <label class="form-left"  style="font-size: 1.2rem;">Email: </label>
                                        <input required type="email" class="form-input" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="center">
                                    <div class="last-name">
                                        <label class="form-right" style="font-size: 1.2rem;">Last Name: </label>
                                        <input required type="text" class="form-input" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="phone">
                                        <label class="form-right" style="font-size: 1.2rem;">Phone Number: </label>
                                        <input required type="tel" class="form-input" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" >           
                                    </div>
                                
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="password">
                                        <label class="form-left" style="font-size: 1.2rem;">Password: </label>
                                        <input required type="text" class="form-input" id="password" placeholder="Password">           
                                    </div>
                    
                                    <div class="confirm-pass">
                                        <label class="form-right" style="font-size: 1.2rem;">Confirm Password: </label>
                                        <input required type="text" class="form-input" id="confirm-pass" placeholder="Confirm Password">            
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                            

                            <div class="container2">
                                <div class="errorMessage"></div>
                                
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">Create Account</button>
                                <h5>Already have an account? <a href="" class="login">Log In</a></h5>
                            </div>
                </form>                        
                        
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </div>
    
</body>
```